# Programming area computation using double meridian

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Formula I am trying to set up]

This is the code I wrote but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Private Sub area_Click()
Dim n As Double
Dim x, r, s, p, y, z As Integer
n = InputBox("No. of Points", "AREA COMPUTATION", "Insert here", 500, 700)
x = n + 1
Range("K2").Formula = "=SUM(E2+E2)"
For p = 3 to x
    r = 3
    For s = 0 to 1
        r = r + s
        Range("K" & p).Formula = "=SUM(Range("K" & (p-1)).Value + Range("E" & r).Value"
    Next s
Next p
y = 3
For z = 3 to x Step 2
    For w = 0 to x
        y = 3 + w
        Range("L2").Formula = "=E2*F2"
        j = Range("K" & z).Value
        u = Range("F" & y).Value
        Range("L" & z).Formula = "u*j"
    Next w
Next z
End Sub
```

Comment: im trying to write a program that will generate the formular depending on the number of points entered and will then enter the formular into the requisite cells in my excell sheet... all cells reffered to (A1:F) already have their traverse computation

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the relevant information rather than linking to pictures of it.

Comment: This is far from clear and doesn't even contain a question. Please write up an explanation about what you're asking about and the relationship between the K and the L columns. Also know that "doesn't seem to work" is far from a problem description. Tell us what you expected, what actually happened, and your thoughts on why it differed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculate the K2 and L2 cell values and the below code will populate the remaining values

```
Sub Foo()

last_row = 13
j = 3
k = 3

For i = 3 To last_row
    'calculate values in column K
    Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(i - 1, 11).Value + Cells(j, 5).Value
    If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then
        'calculate values in column L when the row number is a odd number
        Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i, 11).Value * Cells(k, 6).Value
        k = k + 1
    Else
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

'calculate sum
Cells(last_row + 1, 12).Value = "=sum(L2:L" & last_row & ")"

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry please... pardon me.. new to the forum... thanks for all your kind concerns... the program is meant to input formulars into the different cells in coloum k and L... but after i wrote the program my range.formula doesnt assign the formulas i tried writteing.... besides its saying something about formatting the code... again im new to the forum and i dont really know much about vba.. but i work with excel abit often..